# Does Vow of Enmity guarantee Sneak Attack damage?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat, multi-classing

This has been hinted around at in some other threads, but what's the definitive answer?

Player's Handbook- page 88:

> **Vow of Enmity.** As a bonus action, you can utter a vow of enmity against a creature you can see within 10 feet of you, usin your Channel Divinity. You gain advantage on attack rolls against the creature for 1 minute or until it drops to 0 hit points or falls unconscious.

Player's Handbook- page 96:

> **Sneak Attack.** Beginning at 1st level, you know how to strike subtly and exploit a foe's distraction. Once per turn, you can deal an extra 1d6 damage to one creature you hit with an attack if you have advantage on the attack roll. The attack must use a finesse or a ranged weapon."

So (keeping it simple), if a level 3 Vengeance Paladin/Level 1 Rogue who is using a Scimitar (Finesse Weapon) has VoE on his target, can he add sneak attack to his damage roll once per round without resorting to trying to hide or use stealth?

Comment: For question in the last sentence: it should be Turn, not round. You may also want to include that there aren't any effects giving the character disadvantage.

Comment: My question did not include the word "guarantee" nor was it implied.  I disagree with that edit to my question.

Comment: You can edit your question to remove the "guarantee" wording or rollback the edit.

Comment: It doesn't look like the word impacted the answers, so it's all good (I was worried we would get a list of every variable that removes Advantage, which would not really be the question), as it is it seems fine.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Do you have advantage on the attack roll? Vow of Enmity gives you advantage on attacks for a minute. This assumes there are no effects giving the character disadvantage, balancing everything out to nil.

Is the Weapon Finesse? Scimitars are finesse.

You do an extra d6 of damage.

Comment: or more like, eventually 8d6 or something. sneak attack damage is brutal at higher levels

Comment: @Nemenia Such a statement would require knowing how many levels of Rogue the Paladin/Rogue is going to take. It's 3/1 now, per the question.

Comment: @PremierBromanov yes, but the question is paired down for the sake of simplicity.  Advantage via VoE + Finesse Weapon = Sneak Attack is GO.  In our example the sample character has ONLY one attack per round, he is using a finesse weapon, and the example has NO counter disadvantage presented.  So in the scenario presented the answer is YES, he can use sneak attack.

Comment: @Z.Moe I thought that was fairly obvious, just pointing out that it's not permanent for future users.

Answer (score 7):

If you have advantage you get sneak attack damage.

If you also have disadvantage as well then you no longer have advantage and you don't.

However, this is the **hard** way to get sneak attack.

The **easy** way is to have any ally stand next to your target: the fighter, the mage's familiar, the ranger's animal companion etc. A rogue should get sneak attack almost every round without needing advantage; particularly if they use ranged weapons since they can opportunistically target those enemies who *are* in melee.

Comment: I know you were just filling in the gaps (thank you), and all those details are accurate.  I'm trying to stick to the Scimitar + Shield discussion, because this is less about the best way to use Sneak Attack and more about the pally w/VoE adding Sneak Attack to a Scimitar strike (assuming all variables coincide) because thematically it makes a lot of sense (VoE + Hunter's Mark + Sneak Attack means "I will fight YOU by ANY MEANS NECESSARY")